# PowerShell | Get Storage from Servers with "Get-ADComputer"

Tags: windows, powershell, storage, analysis

i have an problem with my script, plz help :3

This script is supposed to get all Server Hostnames from our Server OU. And than get the Used and Free Space of the Servers But when i try to get the server list with the "Get-AdComputer" cmdlet i get errors.

```
$servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=SomeOU, DC=SomeDomain, DC=SomeDomain, DC=SomeDomain" | Select-Object Name

$allDisks = foreach ($server in $servers)
{
    Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $server -Filter DriveType=3 | 
        Select-Object @{'Name'='ComputerName'; 'Expression'={$server}},
            DeviceID, 
            @{'Name'='Size'; 'Expression'={[math]::truncate($_.size / 1GB)}}, 
            @{'Name'='Freespace'; 'Expression'={[math]::truncate($_.freespace / 1GB)}}
            
}
$allDisks |Export-Csv C:\Servers.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

when i run this i get:

```
Get-WmiObject : Der RPC-Server ist nicht verfügbar.
In Zeile:5 Zeichen:5
+     Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $server -Filter Dri ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

i also should add, that if i only run the thing from the first line i get an clean list of all of our servers.

Comment: How come you think it is the `Get-ADComputer`-line that fails?

Comment: bc when i manually create arrays with Computer names it works flawless

Comment: But it's your `Get-WmiObject`-line that fails, not Get-ADComputer. I'm guessing you're getting servers in the list that are disabled, offline or otherwise not RPC-reachable.

Comment: @CruZer0 - here is a demo of ONE way to query a list of systems _and deal with non-responders_ ... >>> basic remote parallel SystemInfo demo script - Pastebin.com — https://pastebin.com/cGL5biWH

Answer (score 0):

As the error states that RPC server is not available for the one of the servers that you are trying to query. There can be multiple reasons as per the [PS Blog](https://sqlpowershell.blog/2016/05/25/the-rpc-server-is-unavailable-exception-from-hresult-0x800706ba/#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CThe%20RPC%20server%20is%20unavailable,is%20blocked%20by%20the%20firewall.):

**The remote computer is blocked by the firewall.**

Solution: Open the Group Policy Object Editor snap-in (gpedit.msc) to edit the Group Policy object (GPO) that is used to manage Windows Firewall settings in your organization. OpenComputer Configuration, open Administrative Templates, open Network, open Network Connections, open Windows Firewall, and then open either Domain Profile or Standard Profile, depending on which profile you want to configure. Enable the following exception: “Allow Remote Administration Exception” and “Allow File and Printer Sharing Exception“.

**Hostname or IP address is wrong or the remote computer is shut down.**

Solution: Verify correct hostname or IP address.
The “TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper” service isn’t running.
Solution: Verify that “TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper” is running and set to auto start after restart.

**The “Remote Procedure Call (RPC)” service is not running on the remote computer.**

Solution: Verify that “Remote Procedure Call (RPC)” is running and set to auto start after restart.

**The “Windows Management Instrumentation” service is not running on the remote computer.**

Solution: Verify that “Windows Management Instrumentation” is running and set to auto start after restart

So, I dont think there is any code issue there. Kindly check the network firwwall and server side. Also apply a `try/catch` block and capture the exact server name in the loop to see which server is that causing the issue.

Comment: When i use try catch the error dosent seem to be catched. I put the block before the foreach and before the csv export. Is it wrong?

Comment: @CruZer0 Did you set ` -ErrorAction Stop` on the `Get-WmiObject` call inside the try..catch ? Also, put the try..catch **inside** the foreach

Comment: @CruZer0: Can you show me your `try/catch` statement. I dont think you have placed it inside the loop. It must go inside the loop so that in case of failure it will stop. However, if you still want the loop to continue for other servers then you must use  a double `try/catch` - One inside loop and one outside the entire loop.

Comment: @CruZer0: Would like to know about the issue and also would like to know if my answer helped you

Comment: @RanadipDutta The problem was actually much deeper. The problem was that the array wasnt really an array but an "Object" instead. And because Get-WmiObject need "clean strings" for hostnames it didnt worked. It looked like this "@[Name]=Someserver" instead of "Someserver" I fixed this by using "Select-Object - Expand Name" in the first line so the array would get "real and clean strings" After this everthing worked perfectly.

Comment: Oh okay @CruZer0 .. Then you can put that as an answer by yourself and we can mark it as closed